# The screen of ios phonegap application dont show completly in iphone 5 device

Tags: iphone, ios6, cordova, iphone-5

I have an application made ​​with ios phonegap  in itunnes connect. When making a new version of the application I had to adjust it to iphone5. For this, I updated the version of phonegap to 2.8.0 and I have introduced the splash required for the application was validated to iphone5. Once in the  itunnes connect the version 2 of the application I noticed that it looks bad on iphone 5 devices .The app is cut off at the bottom as shown in the image (white rectangle). In iphone 4 works perfectly as shown in the picture.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? thanks!!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem. The HTML5 framework I was using (DHTMLX), has a problem that the new iphone5.

In this forum it is solved: http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=27550